# OneSignal VOIP Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, push-notification, onesignal

I have integrated third party `OneSignal` in my `Swift` Project. From the documentation provided by `OneSignal` I am able to send and receive default `APNS` notification.

But how I can test the `VOIP` notification using `OneSignal` also not found proper and complete documentation on this that is why posted this question.

If anybody worked on this let me know the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any luck with this?. I'm stuck too.